# How to enable SSHFP?

Tags: ssh

I have a domain with DNSSEC enabled, and I would like to use SSHFP.

I checked some guides, but it doesn't work, or maybe it's not enabled correctly.

I'm using a Linode VPS, and I have a DNSSEC activated domain on Cloudflare.

This is what I did (sample):

```
ssh-keygen -r examplehost.example.org
```

then this came out (sample):

```
examplehost.example.org IN SSHFP 1 1 9bd1755b811ba9c9a4416400e7b379d403ca8d11 key 2 and key 3 ...
```

Then I added the records by uploading a TXT to the Cloudflare DNS zone of the domain.

And here is the problem, I """"tested"""" the DNS results by:

```
dig SSHFP yourvps.example.com +short
```

but nothing came out :/

Then I created and edited the txt file “config” at ./ssh know with this:

```
VerifyHostKeyDNS yes
```

Some days later, I couldn't connect any more via the domain/IP address.

Thanks in advance

sources: https://www.vultr.com/docs/use-sshfp-records-to-verify-ssh-host-keys

Comment: Can you show the actual records on Cloudflare? Did you use the correct record type?

Comment: (Side note: You don't need to add _all_ records from ssh-keygen – the ones with `SSHFP x 1` use SHA-1 and can be safely ignored; only the ones with `SSHFP x 2` (SHA-256) are useful. You can also omit `SSHFP 2 y` which is the no-longer-used DSA key type. Altogether you only need 3 records per host, instead of all 8: `ssh-keygen -r foo | awk '$4 != 2 && $5 >= 2'`.)

Comment: Yes, I used this record: https://i.imgur.com/71bSgEJ.png

Comment: And what do you mean by “the ones with SSHFP”? Which ones are? https://i.imgur.com/4HxAK3k.png

Comment: OK I typed that command, so those are the SHA-256. Now I'll upload those 3 records